# string extension method for Session["key"]

Tags: c#, asp.net, extension-methods

At times when we access `Session["key"].ToString()` it gives exception when session is expired & in coding we try to access session variable. So I'm trying to create extension method on `object` class so that I could write it as `Session["key"].getString()` in coding so that every time I don't have to do `Convert.ToString(session["key"])`

Any other solutions are also appreciable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the null-coalescing operator:

```
string value = (session["key"] ?? String.Empty).ToString();
```

**Update**
If you must have a method to do this (extension or otherwise), I would do something like:

```
public static string GetValue(this HttpSessionState session, string key)
{
   // TODO: Insert appropriate error checking here.

   return (session[key] ?? String.Empty).ToString();
}
```

I might even go so far as to make it generic for other possible types with a `GetValue` call that takes a selector and then use lambdas:

```
public static T GetValue<T>(this HttpSessionState session, string key, Func<object, T> valueSelector)
{
    return valueSelector(session[key]);
}

public static string GetStringValue(this HttpSessionState session, string key)
{
    return session.GetValue(key, x => (x ?? String.Empty).ToString());
}
```

You would then use as follows:

```
string value = session.GetStringValue("key");
```

Comment: that would work but an extension method would be preferable as writing this code all over could be cumbersome and repetetive.

Comment: yates can you give short info on how to use generic extension method mentioned above.

Answer (score 5):

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static string GetString(this object o)
    {
        if (o == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        return Convert.ToString(o);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
string value = Session["key"].GetString();
```

or check this one:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static string GetString(this HttpSessionStateBase session, string key)
    {
        if (session == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        var value = session[key];
        if (value == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        return Convert.ToString(value);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
string value = Session.GetString("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can ba an alternative?

```
object oKey = session["key"] ?? String.Empty;
string sKey = (string)oKey;
```

or

```
string sKey = session["key"] == null ? String.Empty : (string)session["key"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also advise using properties for that.

```
protected YourType PropertyName
{
  get 
  {
    if(Session["Sessionname"] != null)
    {
      return Session["Sessionname"] as YourType;
    }
    YourType newItem = new YourType();
    // set vars
    Session["Sessionname"] = newItem;
    return newItem;
  }
  set
  {
   Session["Sessionname"] = value;
  }
}
```

As you can see, I chose `protected` as access modifier. If you want you could put it in a `public class` and make the property `static`.

Or you can use class that derives from `System.Web.UI.Page`.

```
public class MyCustomBaseClass : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected YourType PropertyName
   {
    // get and set like above
    }
}
```

Now you can replace the inheritance in your content pages from `System.Web.UI.Page` to `MyCustomBaseClass` and can easily call `this.PropertyName`.

Comment: it is likely to give option to store object or list of objects or means any data type in session ?

Comment: @Harsh: Every data type that is serializable. Was my answer not useful?

Comment: your answer is also useful but @Jeff Yates's answer was more simple and short that's why I accepted his answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
  public static string SafelyToString(this object o)
  {
     return o != null ? o.ToString() : string.Empty;
  }
}
```

This will allow `Session["key"].SafelyToString()`

You will not however be able to discern between an empty string in the session variable and an expired session.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a easy way to access Session in *Extension method*:

```
var loggedUser = (User)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["User"];
```